# JS : How to capitalize first letter of each symbol-separated word in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

My JS woks well when the string has one word:

- BRUNO ==> Bruno

It works well also when the string is a space sEparated words :

- JEAN MARC ==> Jean Marc

But when it's an underscore separated words i got? :

- JEAN-FRANCOIS ==> Jean-francois ***(wrong)***

My purpose is to generalize it to get that :

- **JEAN-FRANCOIS  ==> Jean-Francois**

How do I make it become LIKE THAT?

**My script is that :**

```
capitalizeString(str) {
    var lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
    return lowerString.replace(/(^| )(\w)/g, (x) => {
      return x.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: what are all available separators you've except `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the hyphen (`-`) as part of the RegEx:

```js
function capitalizeString(str) {
    var lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
    return lowerString.replace(/(^|[ -])(\w)/g, (x) => {
      return x.toUpperCase();
    });
}

console.log(capitalizeString('BRUNO'));
console.log(capitalizeString('JEAN MARC'));
console.log(capitalizeString('JEAN-FRANCOIS'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have many separators you can create an array with them and use it to create your regex dynamically. Like this:

```js
const separators = ['^', ' ', '-'];

const capitalizeString = (str) =>
    str.toLowerCase()
       .replace(new RegExp(`(${separators.join('|')})\\w`, 'g'), (x) => x.toUpperCase());


const s1 = 'BRUNO';
const s2 = 'JEAN MARC';
const s3 = 'JEAN-MARC';

console.log(capitalizeString(s1));
console.log(capitalizeString(s2));
console.log(capitalizeString(s3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalise every first letter as well as every letter after symbols like this:

```js
function capitalizeString(str) {
    var lowerString = str.toLowerCase();
    return lowerString.replace(new RegExp("(?:\\b|_)([a-z])", "g"), (x) => {
      return x.toUpperCase();
    });
}


console.log(capitalizeString("abcd-efgh"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.capitalized = function () {       
    return this.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|[^a-z])[a-z]/g, v => v.toUpperCase());
};
console.log('I-love-YOU-guy'.capitalized());   // => I-Love-You-Guy
```